# Unbiased Estimate of Variance

Tags: regression

Consider a simple linear regression model for $n$ observations where
$$Y_i = \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i$$
where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2).$ I want to show that
$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{\epsilon}_i^2,$$
is an unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$,
where $\hat{\epsilon}_i$ is an unbiased estimate of $\epsilon_i.$
The $n-2$ confused me enough, but when it came to calculating
$E[\hat{\sigma}^2]$, I found that
$$E[\hat{\sigma}^2] = E\left[ \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{i=1}^n \hat{\epsilon}_i^2
\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{i=1}^n E[\hat{\epsilon}_i^2]
= \frac{1}{n-2} \sum_{i=1}^n Var[\hat{\epsilon}_i] + (E[\hat{\epsilon}_i])^2,$$
which uses the definition of variance. However, I am having some difficulty
figuring out $Var[\hat{\epsilon}_i]$, although I am rather sure that
$E[\hat{\epsilon}_i] = \epsilon_i$ given unbiasedness. Note that
we have defined $\hat{\epsilon}_i = (Y_i-\hat{Y}_i)^2,$ where
$\hat{Y}_i = \hat{\beta}X_i$ $ \forall i \in [n].$ Any recommendations on this?

Comment: $\hat{\epsilon}_i$ has mean zero by the unbiasedness assumption (it is not a conditional expectation so saying $E[\hat{\epsilon}_i]=\epsilon_i$ is nonsense; the expectation is a number, not a random variable). So the only question is why $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\epsilon}_i)=\frac{n-2}{n} \sigma^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard assumptions on the noise/error term are $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N} (0, \sigma^2)$. Hence, as was mentioned by @Ian in the comment,
$$
E\hat{\epsilon}_i = E(y_i - \hat{y}_i) = E(y_i) - E(\hat{\beta} x_i)=\beta x_i - \beta x_i=0.
$$